# mac safari, chrome, mozila not support select option line-height css and html

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

Please help me i have create select option in html window all browser supported but mac is not support and line-height, height is not working.
website link [sitemavewebsite](http://sitemaven.dbmonline.net/checkout/)

I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "mac" is not the name of a web browser.  Also your question is incorrectly tagged.

Comment: safari, chrome, mozila